# How do I convert percent encoded slug fields to unicode when migrating from WordPress to Django?

Tags: python, django, url-encoding

I am migrating Wordpress Data into Django. The current site title, content, slug are in Hindi.

I am using wordpress_xmlrpc to import data from WordPress via xmlrpc.

All the content title, content are in Hindi as well, and they are accessed and saved Okay.

```
    instance.name = post.title
    instance.content = post.content
```

While there is issue with Django slugs.

Have the tried the following, does not work.

```
    instance.slug = unicode(post.slug)
    instance.slug = post.slug
```

For not working, in one case, slug is saved as

```
     %e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%a8-%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%a6%e0%a4%bf
```

It is not accessible either.

Getting 404, Page not found for

```
 http://localhost:8010/%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF/
```

The WordPress has slug like
       /तापसी-पन्नू-ने-अक्षय-कुमा/

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work". What goes wrong? [mcve]

Comment: I just updated the question, but the slug is saved as in one case. %e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%a8-%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%a6%e0%a4%bf

Comment: It's [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). What do the slug look like in wordpress?

Comment: What is the debug page of the 404? Do you have a valid url route that should work?

Comment: Slugs at current are like   /तापसी-पन्नू-ने-अक्षय-कुमा/

Comment: A valid url does work, the ones in English, 404 is only for the ones in Hindi.

Comment: What does your url pattern in `urls.py` look like? It might not be compatible with percent encoding.

Comment: the url are
    url(r'^(?P<post>.+)/$', PostView.as_view(), name='post'),

Comment: That looks ok. It might be because the slug is case sensitive? Percent encoding should not be case sensitive ( `%e0` is the same as `%E0` ). It's common to save all slugs as lower case, and do a case insensitive lookup. Something like `page = Post.objects.get(slug=post.lower())`

Comment: Just tried slug=post.lower(), still getting 404

Comment: You should post your view and url code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert percent encoding in the migration, you can use django's built in `uri_to_iri` function.

```
>>> from django.utils.encoding import uri_to_iri
>>> old_slug = '%e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%bf'
>>> new_slug = uri_to_iri(old_slug)
>>> print(old_slug, '->', new_slug)

%e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6-%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%bf -> जल्द-सि
```

This should convert the wordpress slug to unicode:

```
instance.slug = uri_to_iri(post.slug)
```